Htaccess - редирект c товаров на другой раздел
Нужно сделать редирект с раздела, в котором есть товары, на раздел (сохранение пути не нужно).
Например, есть раздел /catalog1/ и в нем товары /catalog1/tovar/ с них нужно сделать редирект на /catalog2/.
PS: Нагуглить подходящее решение не получилось.
